# Em quais casos scanf é seguro? E em quais casos deve, necessariamente, ser substituído por outra função, como fgets?

Tags: c, scanf

É usual se afirmar que `scanf` não é uma função segura. `Clang` e `GCC` não emitem qualquer aviso, porém `MSVC` nem sequer compila (a menos que se inclua `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`):

> Error C4996   'scanf': This function or variable **may be** unsafe.

- Isso significa que em alguns casos `scanf` pode ser usado com segurança e em outros não?
- Em caso afirmativo, quais são esses casos?

Outra função também para leitura de dados é `gets`.

- Há casos em que `gets` pode ser usado com segurança ou deve ser evitado completamente?

Sugere-se usualmente como alternativa a `scanf` e a `gets` o uso de `fgets`.

- De que forma `fgets` é mais seguro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Funções `scanf` e `gets` para processamento de strings

A função [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) é [segura para processamento de strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430978/7838591). Isso porque há um campo específico para delimitar o comprimento da string a ser armazenada. Isso é mostrado no exemplo a seguir.

```
// Exemplo 01   
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7

int main(void)
{
    char cidade[SIZE];
    printf("Insira o nome da sua cidade: ");    // Brasilia
    scanf("%6s", cidade);
    printf("A cidade e: %s", cidade);           // Brasil

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Insira o nome da sua cidade: Brasilia
 * A cidade e: Brasil
 */
```

Se o usuário inserir para o nome da cidade `Brasilia`, não irá ocorrer um [*overflow* do buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), uma vez que `scanf` irá se limitar a tentar armazenar em `cidade` apenas os 6 primeiros caracteres da string, conforme a instrução `%6s` (além de inserir ao final `\0`, que é o *null character*: [referência](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). Por isso, quando o resultado é mostrado na tela aparece como nome da cidade `Brasil`.

O inconveniente é que o limite para o comprimento da string não pode ser inserido como argumento de modo direto, ao contrário de [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Mais detalhes no **Complemento**.

O processamento de strings também pode ser realizado pela função [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets). Entretanto, `gets` não apresenta qualquer campo delimitador e irá realizar a leitura até encontrar uma nova linha ou o fim do arquivo (EOF). Reescrevendo o exemplo anterior para `gets`:

```
// Exemplo 02   
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7

int main(void)
{
    char cidade[SIZE];
    printf("Insira o nome da sua cidade: ");    // Brasilia
    gets(cidade);
    printf("A cidade e: %s", cidade);           // ???

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possivel Output ##
 * Insira o nome da sua cidade: Brasilia
 * A cidade e: Brasilia
 */
```

Dessa forma, `gets` tenta armazenar em `cidade` a string completa, o que não é possível, afinal `cidade` não comporta uma string de 8 caracteres. No caso testado, `gets` invadiu os endereços de memória adjacentes para escrever a parte da string que não era possível armazenar em `cidade`, resultando em um *overflow* do buffer. Se for inserida uma string suficientemente longa, a tendência é que além de acontecer um *overflow* do buffer, ele também cause uma falha de segmentação (mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685413/what-is-the-difference-between-a-segmentation-fault-and-a-stack-overflow) e [aqui](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-different-between-Buffer-Overflow-with-Segmentation-Fault)). Buffer *overflow* é uma das principais vulnerabilidades exploradas por hackers e por isso deve se ter uma atenção especial a essa questão (vídeo: [ataque via buffer *overflow* na prática](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo). Texto: [Buffer Overflow Exploit](https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Buffer-Overflow-Exploit/)). Dessa forma, pela falta de um campo que delimite o comprimento da string a ser armazenada é impossível realizar a leitura de strings de modo seguro por `gets` (e a leitura de strings é a única função de `gets`). Por isso, `gets` nunca deve ser usado e foi [removido completamente da linguagem a partir de C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets).

### Funções `scanf` e `fgets` para processamento de dados aritméticos

Além de strings, `scanf` também realiza a leitura de dados aritméticos (valores inteiros e de ponto flutuante). Entretanto, [para esse caso, scanf não é seguro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430978/7838591), não havendo garantia de proteção garantida contra comportamento indefinido. O código seguinte ilustra isso. Uma vez que a [C *standard* especifica apenas o valor absoluto mínimo dos tipos inteiros](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), o valor de `LONG_MIN` e `LONG_MAX` dependem da implementação, porém obrigatoriamente `LONG_MIN <= -2147483647` e `LONG_MAX >= +2147483647`).

```
// Exemplo 03    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {

    long a;
    char buffer[SIZE];

    printf("Digite o numero: ");            // 2147483648 (LONG_MAX + 1)
    int success = scanf("%ld", &a);
    printf("a = %ld", a);
    getchar();

    printf("\nDigite o numero: ");          // 2147483648
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    long b = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
    if (b == LONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("b: Overflow!\n");
    }
    else if (b == LONG_MIN && errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("b: Underflow!\n");
    }       
    printf("b = %ld", b);       

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possivel Output ##
 * Digite o numero: 2147483648
 * a = -2147483648
 * Digite o numero: 2147483648
 * b: Overflow! 
 * b = 2147483647 
 */
```

O usuário entra com um número suficientemente grande de modo que o tipo `long` seja incapaz de armazenar (ler **Observação**). `Scanf` lê o número e retorna `1` (o retorno de `scanf` indica o número de valores atribuídos com sucesso). Entretanto, acontece *overflow* e de acordo com a C *Standard* o [*overflow* de inteiros resulta em comportamento indefinido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484643/wrap-around-of-integers-in-c). No teste realizado com o exemplo, o que ocorreu foi a atribuição à variável `a` do valor `-2147483648`. Isso indica que houve o que se conhece como [wraparound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484643/wrap-around-of-integers-in-c). Entretanto, [`scanf` não permite testar a ocorrência de *overflow* de inteiros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007600/detecting-integral-overflow-with-scanf). A situação pode ser amenizada buscando impor um limite ao valor lido. Considerando um `long` em que `LONG_MAX` é `+2147483647`, é possível impor um limite escrevendo `scanf("%9ld", number)`. Nota-se que um valor com 10 dígitos (`%10ld`) já abriria margem para *overflow* (`+9 999 999 999 > +2 147 483 647`). Entretanto, impondo-se o limite de 9 dígitos, o que acontece é que existe um intervalo de números que são válidos (`long` comporta), porém o código exclui das possibilidades. Por sua vez, `fgets` oferece proteção. Primeiramente, no código, `fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin)` limita o valor lido, impedindo a ocorrência de *overflow* do buffer, o que poderia ser crítico. Na sequência, `strtol` realiza a conversão para o tipo `long`: `long b = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10)`. Não é possível armazenar o valor em um tipo `long`, então `strtol`:

1. Retorna o maior inteiro possível: `LONG_MAX`. Com isso, evita a ocorrência de *overflow* da variável `b`.
2. Seta a flag [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) para [`ERANGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=msvc-170) indicando que um erro ocorreu, especificamente um valor processado com magnitude excessivamente grande.

Destaca-se que [`scanf` não seta `errno`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007600/detecting-integral-overflow-with-scanf) impedindo que estratégia semelhante seja adotada em `scanf`.

Nota-se que a lógica de `fgets` é segura. Mesmo que se tente um ataque baseado em *overflow*, todos os comportamentos estão bem definidos. Não haverá *overflow* de buffer e nem um *integer overflow* da variável `b`, que estará obrigatoriamente no seu intervalo de validade.

Se for um tipo `float`, a situação é mais sutil. De acordo com a IEEE 754, se um número for excessivamente grande para ser armazenado em um tipo `float`, deve se atribuir à variável o valor especial `inf` ou `-inf` (tópico 7.4 da IEEE 754 e abordado [aqui](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800207) [tópico 2 Overflow and underflow] e [aqui](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00779764/document) [tópico: 2.3.2 Overflow]). Entretanto, isso não consta na C *standard*. Portanto, um compilador pode ou não reproduzir o comportamento descrito na IEEE 754. Caso haja obediência à IEEE 754, o comportamento de `scanf`, ao ler um número excessivamente grande, será atribuir à variável do tipo `float` o valor especial `inf` ou `-inf`. Esse é um comportamento definido e, nesse sentido, seguro. Isso é ilustrado no código abaixo.

```
// Exemplo 04
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    float a;
    printf("Digite o numero: ");              // 2E40
    int success = scanf("%f", &a);            // 1

    if (isinf(a)) {
        printf("Underflow ou Overflow!\n");   // Underflow ou Overflow!
    }
    printf("a = %f", a);                      // inf

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possível Output ##
 * Digite o numero: 2E40
 * Underflow ou Overflow!
 * a = inf
 */
```

Esse código foi testado no MSVC, Clang, GCC e TCC. Em todos a variável `a` recebeu o valor especial `inf`. Entretanto, compiladores C não são obrigados a obedecerem à IEEE 754 e, portanto, `scanf` não é seguro em relação ao armazenamento de números em ponto flutuante.

Por outro lado, a estratégia por `fgets` envolve duas operações sequenciais:

1. `fgets` armazena o valor lido como string em um array de char
2. `strtof` realiza a conversão da string para `float`

A primeira operação é segura, conforme o exemplo 3. A segunda operação também é segura, uma vez que o seu comportamento é determinado pela própria [C *standard*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). Se o valor convertido por `strtof` estiver fora do intervalo válido, então `HUGE_VALF` é retornado ([referência](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)). Com isso, há a certeza de um comportamento definido.

Portanto, o processamento de valores ponto flutuantes pela estratégia por meio de `fgets` é segura. O código abaixo é a versão com `fgets` do Exemplo 4.

```
// Exemplo 05
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50    

int main(void) {

    char buffer[SIZE ];
    float a;
    printf("Digite o numero: ");          // 2E40        
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;    // remove '\n'    
    a = strtof(buffer, NULL);

    if (isinf(a)) {
        printf("Underflow ou Overflow!\n");
    }
    printf("a = %f", a);                  // +inf

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Digite o numero: 2E40
 * Underflow ou Overflow!
 * a = inf
 */
```

Estratégia de `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0`: [referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/7838591).

### Função `fgets` para processamento de strings

Além do processamento de dados aritméticos, `fgets` também pode ser usado para processamento de strings, como substituto a `scanf`. O primeiro exemplo com `scanf` pode ser adaptado para  uma versão alternativa com `fgets`.

```
// Exemplo 06
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7
    
int main(void) {

    char cidade[SIZE];
    printf("Insira o nome da sua cidade: ");   // Brasilia
    fgets(cidade, SIZE, stdin);
    printf("A cidade e: %s", cidade);          // Brasil

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Insira o nome da sua cidade: Brasilia
 * A cidade e: Brasil
 */
```

Da mesma forma que `scanf`, `fgets` também oferece proteção contra *overflow* do buffer. Entretanto, ao contrário de `scanf`, em `fgets` o valor máximo para o número de caracteres na string pode ser inserido de modo direto como um argumento, nesse caso, inserido por meio de `SIZE` (mais informações no **Complemento**).

---

#### Complemento

Com `printf` é possível inserir o valor para o campo delimitador por meio de um argumento. O exemplo a seguir ilustra isso:

```
// Exemplo 07
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6

int main(void) {

    char cidade[20] = "Brasilia";   
    printf("%.*s \n", SIZE, cidade);    // Brasil
    printf("%.6s \n", cidade);          // Brasil
    
    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Brasil
 * Brasil
 */
```

Para `scanf` a única **estratégia direta** é a análoga ao do segundo `printf`. Isso é uma desvantagem uma vez que o campo delimitador via argumento, ao contrário da estratégia *"hardcoded"*, permite trabalhar com facilidade casos em que o valor é proveniente de:

- Uma variável de outro arquivo
- Um argumento inserido pelo usuário

E ainda conveniente se for usado em diversos `printf`.

**Observação:** é possível `scanf` receber o valor para o campo delimitador via argumento, porém não de modo direto. Detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415909/7838591) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/7838591).

---

#### Observação

Um buffer *overflow* significa de fato um extravasamento de dados, resultando em uma invasão a regiões de memória não pertencentes à variável. Em um *integer overflow* (ou floating *overflow*) não necessariamente acontece essa invasão. Ao se referir a esse tipo de *overflow* se faz alusão à **tentativa** de atribuição de um valor a uma variável que é incapaz de armazenar tal valor devido a magnitude excessiva dele. Para um *integer overflow*, isso configura comportamento indefinido, podendo resultar em um buffer *overflow* (invasão de memória), um wraparound, etc. Essa lógica é a que se deduz pela IEEE 754 e ela é adotada aqui. Entretanto, [pode-se argumentar em contrário](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-wrap-around-overflow), uma posição bastante lógica.

---

#### Tópico Adicional:

#### Particularidades de `scanf`, `gets` e `fgets` no processamento de strings

O comportamento padrão da função `scanf` é parar a leitura no primeiro [`whitespace`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) encontrado ([referência](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-fscanf-scanf-sscanf-read-format-data)). Entretanto, o `whitespace` é deixado no buffer de entrada. Portanto, o código a seguir não está correto:

```
// Exemplo 08
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main() {

    char cidade[SIZE];
    char estado[SIZE];

    printf("Cidade: ");           // Manaus  
    scanf("%19s", cidade);
    printf("Estado: ");
    fgets(estado, 20, stdin);

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possível Output ##
 * Cidade: Manaus
 * Estado:
 */
```

O que acontece é que `scanf` realiza a leitura da cidade inserida pelo usuário e deixa no buffer de entrada `\n`. Com isso, `fgets` lê o restante do buffer de entrada (`\n`) e armazena na variável `estado`. Com isso, o usuário não consegue inserir o estado. Para corrigir esse código é necessário inserir `getchar` após cada `scanf`. Entretanto, essa proteção falha se o usuário inserir para a variável `cidade` a sequência: Manaus <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>. O programa retorna ao problema inicial: `getchar` irá remover o espaço do buffer, porém a nova linha permanecerá no buffer. Uma alternativa para que esse problema também seja resolvido é substituir `getchar` por `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`. Com isso, será limpo do buffer de entrada tudo após o último caractere processado por `scanf` até se encontrar uma nova linha ou o fim do arquivo. Portanto, para essa solução, cada `getchar` seria substituído por:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

Para ambos os casos, `fgets` já provê intrinsicamente a proteção necessária. Isso porque `fgets` lê até uma nova linha, fim do arquivo ou alcançar o número de caracteres delimitados, o que acontecer primeiro ([referência](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)). No caso em questão, a nova linha é o que acontece primeiro e ela é incluída na variável associada (no caso `cidade` ou `estado`) e removida do buffer de entrada. De modo semelhante, `gets` lê até que seja encontrada uma nova linha ou o fim do arquivo. Caso seja encontrada uma nova linha, ela é incluída na variável associada ([referência](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets)).

Por fim, diversas particularidades de `scanf` e `fgets` são exploradas [aqui](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

---

### Conclusão

> Isso significa que em alguns casos `scanf` pode ser usado com segurança
> e em outros não?

Sim. O processamento de strings pode ser realizado com segurança por `scanf`. Entretanto, no processamento de valores inteiros e de ponto flutuante não há garantia.

> Há casos em que `gets` pode ser usado com segurança ou deve ser evitado
> completamente?

Deve ser evitado completamente. A função `gets` é segura apenas em ambientes em que se imponha limites à `stdin`, o que é um caso muito específico.

> De que forma `fgets` é mais segura?

A função `fgets` proporciona segurança tanto no processamento de strings como no de dados aritméticos (inteiros e de ponto flutuante).